# O que significa a expressão !(...)?

Tags: r, rscript

Eu não consegui descobrir o que significa a expressão `!(...)`

Exemplo:

```
if (!(book %in% books))
    stop("Unknown book")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qualquer coisa que você coloque dentro de um if("Qualquer coisa") será transformada em true ou false. O corpo do if só executa se o resultado for true.

No seu caso como há o caracter '!' indica uma negação do IF, ou seja "Não Se"

**Sua expressão está querendo dizer:**

> Se NÃO houver livro (book) na coletânea de livros (books) faça
>
> Pare a execução da expressão e exiba uma mensagem (que no seu caso
> será: "Unknown book")

Resumindo, sua função está procurando um livro em uma lista, e caso não encontre retorna uma mensagem.

Answer (score 2):

É um operador de lógica binária. Tem a função de negação, conhecimento como `not`. Ela nega o retorno do termo subjacente. Se o retorno é `verdadeiro` o operador `!` renderá a expressão como `falsa`.

*A linguagem parece R.*